# Find path dir from mysql in php

Tags: php

I currently saving all my file paths in the database like this

```
 ID   |      file_path
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  1         home/games/ps3/cod.png
  2         home/err.png
  3         home/games/ps3logo.png
  4         home/games/xboxlogo.png
  5         home/games/pclogo.png
  6         home/games/wiilogo.png
  7         home/msg.png
```

I am trying to use php to search all the files and get the files from the dir you selected

```
$folder_path = "home/games/ps3";
```

I only want to show all the images in the ps3 folder?

Comment: Are you asking how to list all files in a given directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a REGEX like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_path RLIKE '^".$folder_path."/[^/]*\$'";
```

The query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM files
WHERE file_path RLIKE '^home/games/ps3/[^/]*$'
```

Comment: Really?  That's odd.  What did it return?

Comment: Make sure $folder_path doesn't have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, you should just be able to do a query like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_path LIKE '".$folder_path."%'";
```

That will return all rows where the file_path column starts with whatever value the PHP `$folder_path` variable contains.

Comment: but if i was to have a dir call home/games/ps3/cod/match2/   it would show dat aswell i have tryed it already

Comment: Then you could add a second condition, I suppose, like this: `WHERE file_path LIKE '".$folder_path."%' AND file_path NOT LIKE '%/'"`. Not a great way of doing it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path, you can use the 'readdir' function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```
$folder_path = "home/games/ps3";

if ($handle = opendir($folder_path)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        // Do whatever you want with $file
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```